# MessageDigest.digest() returning same hash for different strings having Norwegian character

Tags: java, hash, message-digest, password-policy

I am calling `MessageDigest.digest()` method to get the hash of the password.
If the password contains a Norwegian character e.g. `'ø'`, this method returns same hash for different strings with different last character.
`"Høstname1"`  and `"Høstname2"` have same hash but `"Hostnøme1"` will have a different hash as `'ø'` location is different. This is with "utf-8" encoding. For "iso-8859-1" encoding, I am not seeing this issue. Is this a known problem or am I missing something here?

*This is my code:*

```
    import java.security.MessageDigest;

    String password = "Høstname1";
    String salt = "6";

    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hash = new byte[40];
    messageDigest.update(salt.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, salt.length());
    messageDigest.update(password.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, password.length());
    hash = messageDigest.digest();
```

Comment: Just a guess but it might have something to do with the encoding of your sourcefile and the encoding set for the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the length of the string to `messageDigest.update`

```
messageDigest.update(password.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, password.length());
```

but the length of the byte array since the utf-8 encoded string usually has more bytes than the number of characters in the string:

```
byte[] pwd = password.getBytes("utf-8");
messageDigest.update(pwd, 0, pwd.length);
```

or even shorter (thanks @Matt)

```
messageDigest.update(password.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

Same for `salt`.

Therefore your code was only hashing the beginning of the password.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.
I am just wondering why was working earlier with all the English characters.

Comment: @namang029 if all characters in the password are < 128 then `password.getBytes("utf-8").length == password.length()` so you didn't notice the bug

Comment: @namang029 use the overload without the length so you don't have to worry about whether or not you're making this mistake